# Teradata/SQL, select all rows until a certain value is reached per partition

Tags: sql, teradata

I'd like to select all rows from a table until (and including) a certain value is reached per partition. In this case all rows per id that precede when status has the value 'b' for the last time. Note: the timestamp is in order per id

| id | name | status | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | open | a | 10:50:09.000000 |
| 1 | Danny | open | c | 10:50:19.000000 |
| 1 | Elle | closed | b | 10:50:39.000000 |
| 2 | anton | closed | a | 16:00:09.000000 |
| 2 | jill | done | b | 16:00:19.000000 |
| 2 | tom | open | b | 16:05:09.000000 |
| 2 | bill | open | c | 16:07:09.000000 |
| 3 | ann | done | b | 08:00:13.000000 |
| 3 | stef | done | b | 08:12:13.000000 |
| 3 | martin | open | b | 08:25:13.000000 |
| 3 | jeff | open | a | 09:00:13.000000 |
| 3 | luke | open | c | 09:07:13.000000 |
| 3 | karen | open | c | 09:15:13.000000 |
| 3 | lucy | open | a | 10:00:13.000000 |

The output would look like this:

| id | name | status | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | open | a | 10:50:09.000000 |
| 1 | Danny | open | c | 10:50:19.000000 |
| 1 | Elle | closed | b | 10:50:39.000000 |
| 2 | anton | closed | a | 16:00:09.000000 |
| 2 | jill | done | b | 16:00:19.000000 |
| 2 | tom | open | b | 16:05:09.000000 |
| 3 | ann | done | b | 08:00:13.000000 |
| 3 | stef | done | b | 08:12:13.000000 |
| 3 | martin | open | b | 08:25:13.000000 |

I've tried to solve this using qualify with rank etc. but unfortunately with no succes. would be appreciated if somebody would be able to help me!

Comment: What if there's no status 'b' for an id, do you want all rows returned or no rows?

Answer (score 2):

*all rows per id that precede when status has the value 'b' for the last time* is the same as *no rows before value 'b' occurs the first time* when you revert the sort order:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
QUALIFY -- tag the last 'b'
   Count(CASE WHEN status = 'b' THEN 1 end) 
   Over (PARTITION BY id
         ORDER BY timestamp DESC
         ROWS Unbounded Preceding) > 0
ORDER BY id, timestamp
;
```

This will not return ids where no 'b' exists.

If you want to return those, too, add another condition to QUALIFY:

```
OR -- no 'b' found
   Count(CASE WHEN status = 'b' THEN 1 end) 
   Over (PARTITION BY id) = 0
```

As both counts share the same partition, it's still a single STAT step in Explain.

Comment: thanks! It works almost like intended but maybe I was not clear. I meant the rows per id that precede when status has the value 'b' for the last time, for the first time.

In a column of a, a, b, b c, b, b I would like it to return a, a, b, b